How can I detect which channels contain compressed audio in a video file by using command line tools?
I have an MXF file that contains 16 audio tracks.  I know the first two tracks (stereo) contain Dolby E compressed video.  Using MediaInfo (gui) it lists 16 audio streams with a mix of Dolby E and PCM as shown in this link:
MediaInfo GUI
I need a way to get this information from the command line.  I tried "ffmpeg -i channel_mapping_1080i2997_5.1_2_comp.mxf -f null -" but it shows 16 PCM tracks:
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24be, 48000 Hz, hexadecagonal, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s
...
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))

Can ffmpeg or some other command line program be used to obtain this information?  I specifically need to know which audio tracks contain compressed data and which are PCM.

Have you tried ffprobe -print_format json -show_format -show_streams? Does it also claim all are PCM? Are you 100% sure that they're not PCM?

Try: ffprobe -v error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=index,codec_name -of csv=p=0 channel_mapping_1080i2997_5.1_2_comp.mxf

Support for identifying Dolby-E in MXF is disabled in ffmpeg, likely because there was no decoder at the time. Can you share a small sample?

Attie, Rotem: Neither of these commands gave any additional information than what I already had.
Gyan: I think you are probably right about ffmpeg.

MediaInfo has a command line version (which I did not know about when I posted my question).  It looks like that gives all the information I need.
$ mediainfo --Inform="Audio;%ID%  %Format%\n" channel_mapping_1080i2997_5.1_2_comp.mxf 
3-1 / 2-1  Dolby E
3-1 / 2-2  Dolby E
3-3  PCM
3-4  PCM
3-5  PCM
3-6  PCM
3-7  PCM
3-8  PCM
3-9  PCM
3-10  PCM
3-11  PCM
3-12  PCM
3-13  PCM
3-14  PCM
3-15  PCM
3-16  PCM

